# How come React.js Conditional rendering doesn't work iOS 9 and below?

Tags: ios, reactjs, if-statement, rendering, state

I have multiple components that follow this rendering structure if I am fetching data from a database. Basically, on componentWillMount() I fetch data from my API, while this is happening a spinner gets displayed on the screen, which is the else if statement. Once data is loaded the if statement is supposed to run which works on my desktop, and iPhone 5 & iPad mini on iOS 11. However, if I test my website on my iPhone 6, and iPad which are on iOS 9.3.3. The website gets stuck on the second else if statement. Basically, the spinner just stays, and never switches to show the data when it loads. Is this an iOS 9 issue or is it based on how I wrote my rendering function?
I should add that this rendering format works on some pages and on other pages it does not work. Using if the page is doing a nested render it will not work.
[Sample code that doesn't work](https://github.com/KanteLabs/Clothing-Marketplace/blob/master/client/src/components/WishList.jsx)

[Code that does work](https://github.com/KanteLabs/Clothing-Marketplace/blob/master/client/src/components/ReadArticle.jsx)

```
renderPage(){
    if(this.state.productDataLoaded && this.state.productData){
        return(
            <div className="single-brand">
                <h1 className="ui header">Shopping Bag</h1>
                <div className="page-container ui container">
                    {this.renderClothing()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }else if(this.state.productDataLoaded === false ){
        return(
            <div className="ui active inverted dimmer">
                <div className="ui indeterminate text loader">Preparing Files</div>
            </div>
        )
    }else{
        return(
            // returns 404
        )
    }
}
render(){
    return(
        <section id="cart">
            {this.renderPage()}
        </section>
    )
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the if statements are wrong. Smells to me more like a resource fetching issue and handling of the response

Comment: I tried on multiple phones though. It works on androids as well. Have you looked at the sample code? I think that maybe the state change doesn't get read well on older iOS.

Comment: Did you scaffold your app using `create-react-app`?

Comment: Also if `this.state.productData` isn't a boolean...you should cast the expression using the `!!` operator. Even though if there is data its not considered a "falsey" value its still best not to use type coercion.

e.g. `if ( this.state.productDataLoaded && !!this.state.productData )`

Why? Because [ ] = true.

Comment: Yes I did scaffold it with create-react-app. What kind of issues can that cause? And thank you for the neat little trick.